# Unable to load asset: maher.jpg

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

all dependencies are up to date
and i get dependencies work; this is my pubspec.yaml file:
[pubspec.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb0Pl.png)

and this is main.dart file:
[main file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZObI6.png)

I tried every way but failed!
please help!

I tried every way for loading assets on my physical device but failed!
please help!

Comment: Do not post code as images.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the path, including the directory "images" that you have set in the pubspec.yaml file.

I.e.

```
Image.asset('images/maher.jpg')
```

Assuming your image is located directly in the images folder.